# Como mostrar una imagen por ruta en C#

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework

Estoy trabajando en C# MVC en web y necesito mostrar una imágen donde la ruta la tengo guardada en la bd, pero la imagen está almacenada en un servidor externo

Mi inconveniente es que no puedo ver la imagen que estoy llamando con la ruta, porque está fuera de la solución

¿Que debo hacer?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! mvc es una arquitectura, pero no nos dice en que estas trabajando.. supongo que es web, pero la verdad, yo he visto mvc en escritorio.. ademas... cual es el problema que tuviste poniendo la ruta en el control que usas para mostrar imagenes?

Comment: Donde este la solucion no tiene nada que ver con las cosas que podes mostrar o no... y si agregas un ejemplo?